# como conectar ao banco de dados PHPmyadm?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

ele dar esse erro aqui:
 Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

nao consigo fazer a conexao com o banco de dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você esqueceu de colocar um "i"...

`$con = new mysqli($Conexao, $User $Senha, $Database))`

Isso Cria a Conexão Pra ti, onde:
`$Conexao = localhost (no teu caso)`
`$Database = Nome da tua base de dados`...

`$consulta = "SUA QUERY";
$resultado = $con->query($consulta );`

Isso Executa a Query pra ti.

`while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Dado: ".$row["dado"].";";
 }`

Com esse While tu pega os dados que tua consulta Retornou.